# 18.04.3 How do I make sure that my dedicated graphics card is used and not my integrated one?

Tags: drivers, 18.04, graphics, amd-graphics, hybrid-graphics

A bit of background information: I have recently bought an ASUS TUF FX505 with an AMD Ryzen 5 3550H CPU and an AMD Radeon RX 560X GPU. The system I have installed is Ubuntu 18.04.3.

However, the CPU has an integrated graphics card and I am not sure if Ubuntu is really using the dedicated GPU.

`lspci|grep VGA` shows me only the integrated card, but `sudo lshw -C video` shows both cards, so at least my system detected the dedicated GPU, but even if I only look at a bunch of images, my fans tend to go into overdrive, sounding like a helicopter before liftoff. Thus I suspect that the dedicated GPU is not in use, but how do I check that?

And if ubuntu is using the wrong card, how do I force it to use the other one?

Comment: The monitor is plugged on the Gcard or mainboard? Did you setup bios setting for graphics preferences?

Comment: It is a laptop, I guess the monitor is plugged into the mainboard. I tried to setup UEFI in that regard, but my options seem to be very limited, even the "advanced" ones.

Comment: this may help to know which GPU is in use : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/36785/348533 - Next step will be to load wanted / unload unwanted module